# Simple computation question about the limit of a function including little oh

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Consider a sequence

$$c_n:= t + o(t/n)n$$ where $o(\cdot)$ denotes little-oh

I want to compute $\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n =?$

I guessing the result should be $\lim_{n\to \infty} c_n = t$ but not sure. Can some one help to say more word about how to do the computation in such kind format explicitly? e.g., can I treat $o(t/n)n = o(t) ?$ and how to get the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c_n = t + na_n$, for some sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n \in o(t/n)$. This means

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{\frac{t}{n}}=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{na_n}{t}=0
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (t + na_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} t\left(1 + \frac{na_n}{t}\right)= t\left(1 + \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{na_n}{t}\right)=t(1+0)=t.
$$

Comment: Thanks, @karakusc, but I don't get your last step. I mean how to get $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n =t$? why not $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n =t + o(t)$?

Comment: $o(t)$ means something that grows strictly slower than $t$. Since $t$ is constant, it means something that goes to zero. See edit to see how it works.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much. @ karakusc